# Using native code in java

Tags: java, c, linux, java-native-interface, javah

I want to create c library and use it in my java code on an Linux OS. I'm trying to understand and implement natural library concept. 
 I'm following this tutorial
http://diglib.stanford.edu:8091/~testbed/doc/JavaUsage/JNI/tutorial.txt

Which is helpful me to understand concept a little. However, I get errors when I try to do it myself. I searced for errors I am getting but none of solutions helped.

Main class code and class for natural library I wrote is as follows:

```
package natLib;
import natLib.getKeyPressed;
public class main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    getKeyPressed natlab=new getKeyPressed();
    char c=natlab.keyboardPressedKey();

}
}

package natLib;    
public class getKeyPressed {
static {
 System.loadLibrary("natlab");
    }
public native char keyboardPressedKey();
}
```

when I write "javac main.java"
I get errors like

"main.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
        getKeyPressed natlab=new getKeyPressed();"

And when I skip for main and just do javac prcess for class with native method, try to obtain a header file 
 javah -jni getKeyPressed.class

Although there is a file as getKeyPressed.class, I get errors like:

```
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a valid class name:     getKeyPressed.class"
```

I try it without .class extention it says

```
"Error: Could not find class file for 'getKeyPressed'."
```

It says that even when I make getKeyPressed class file by copying getKeyPressed.class.

It seems I am making a major mistake, any suggestions to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

javah expects a fully qualified classname.   (e.g. natLib.getKeyPressed, not just getKeyPressed)

Comment: And so that's without the file extension (.class). It's very similar to the java command.

Comment: Thanks, I solved it. In addition to what you said, I should have used javah command at the parent directory of package directory.

Comment: @şirketiçin That's going to be the case with most java tools you'll  ever use, since the package structure and directory structure are tightly coupled together.